# Remove from nested array by sub id , "nModified" : 0

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to remove data from a sub array as follow but am having difficulties.

```
{
  "_id" : "0",
  "mainArray" : [
      {
        "price" : 12,
        "informations" : [
          {
            "createdBy" : "0x957a1a87d653ea2218742aeea5a05f637b6509c4",
            "orderId" : 1
          },
          {
            "createdBy" : "0x957a1a87d653ea2218742aeea5a05f637b6509c4",
            "orderId" : 2
          }
        ]
      },{
        "price" : 45,
        "informations" : [
          {
            "createdBy" : "0x957a1a87d653ea2218742aeea5a05f637b6509c4",
            "orderId" : 5
          },
          {
            "createdBy" : "0x957a1a87d653ea2218742aeea5a05f637b6509c4",
            "orderId" : 6
          }
        ]
      }
```

I would like the output to be :

```
{
  "_id" : "0",
  "mainArray" : [
      {
        "price" : 12,
        "informations" : [
          {
            "createdBy" : "0x957a1a87d653ea2218742aeea5a05f637b6509c4",
            "orderId" : 1
          },
          {
            "createdBy" : "0x957a1a87d653ea2218742aeea5a05f637b6509c4",
            "orderId" : 2
          }
        ]
      },{
        "price" : 45,
        "informations" : [
          {
            "createdBy" : "0x957a1a87d653ea2218742aeea5a05f637b6509c4",
            "orderId" : 5
          }
        ]
      }
```

I've tried this :

```
db.collection.update({ "_id": "0" }, { $pull: { 'mainArray.informations': { "orderId": 6 } } });
```

and

```
db.collection.update({ "_id": "0" }, { $pull: { 'mainArray.0.informations': { "orderId": 6 } } });
```

But both don't work, the best i'm getting :

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Anyone see where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: Test your second codes `db.coll.update({_id: '0'}, {$pull:{'mainArray.0.informations': {'orderId': 6}}})` and the result is 
`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })` under mogno v3.2.3

Comment: i keep on getting WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 }) i don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the positional operator '$' . `$` is a [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array

```
    db.collection.update({ "_id": "0" ,"mainArray.informations.orderId":6 },
                     { $pull: { 'mainArray.$.informations': { "orderId": 6 } } });
```

> Note : the array field must appear as part of the query document to figure out the matching position in mainArray.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for helping. You're right it's an issue with the index in the array because my example didn't represent my data well. I've updated my example, and you're right it does work when providing the right index, but the issue is that i'm not supposed to know the index but only the OrderId and price so that's not really dynamic. With $ i'm getting : ` writeError" : {
  "code" : 16837,
  "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: mainArray.$.informations"`